# Use of glossaries inside mhchem and chemformula

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, mhchem, chemmacros

I noticed that when I use `glossaries` package with `mhchem` (inside `\ce{...}`), the abbreviation is always italicized (which is undesired), whereas with `chemformula` everything works as expected (`\ch{...}`).

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? How to get consistent and properly rendered (I use XeLaTeX and makeglossaries) abbreviations with both packages without using obvious `\mathrm` or `\text` sequences in `\newacronym` or `\newglossaryentry`?

MWE and what it renders to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage[modules=all]{chemmacros}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{DMSO}{DMSO}{dimethyl sulfoxide}
\newglossaryentry{b.p.}{name={b.p.},description={boiling point}}

\begin{document}
\glsunsetall    

\Gls{DMSO} (\gls{b.p.} 189) is used to obtain \ce{[CrCl2(\gls{DMSO})4]+} (mhchem) | \ch{[CrCl2(\gls{DMSO})4]+} (chemformula)

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell `\ce` tries to parse the argument and can't pick up stuff that's embedded. The same problem occurs if you do `\newcommand{\DMSO}{DMSO}` and `\ce{[CrCl2(\DMSO)4]+}`.

Comment: To escape parsing within `\ce{..}`, enclose the `\gls{DMSO}` in a pair of braces, like `\ce{[CrCl2({\gls{DMSO}})4]+}`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thank you for the explanation and quick respond, as well as for maintaining the mighty `glossaries` package!

Comment: @Troy Now I feel stupid, jut using `{\gls{DMSO}}` did the trick. I guess you might want to convert your comment to an answer:)

Comment: BTW: you are mistaking `chemmacros` for `chemformula`…

Comment: @clemens I thought passing option `[modules=all]` loads `chemformula` too. Is it better to declare the use of `chemformula` *via* `\usepackage{chemformula}`?

Comment: @andselisk That's not what I mean: the package `chemmacros` does not define `\ch`.  Saying the result `\ch{...}` is from `chemmacros` is misleading because the macro is defined by the `chemformula` package.

Comment: @clemens Oh, sorry for misunderstanding, I edited my question. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nicola rightfully pointed out, this is not an issue with `\gls` and friends, and instead is an issue about the `\ce{...}` command from `mhchem` package trying to parse its arguments.

To escape parsing within `\ce{..}`, enclose the `\gls{DMSO}` in a pair of braces, like `\ce{[CrCl2({\gls{DMSO}})4]+}`.
Refer to the 'Escape Parsing, Upright Text' in the `mhchem` package documentation for more details.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage[modules=all]{chemmacros}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{DMSO}{DMSO}{dimethyl sulfoxide}
\newglossaryentry{b.p.}{name={b.p.},description={boiling point}}

\begin{document}
    \glsunsetall    

    \Gls{DMSO} (\gls{b.p.} 189) is used to obtain \ce{[CrCl2({\gls{DMSO}})4]+} (mhchem) | \ch{[CrCl2(\gls{DMSO})4]+} (chemmacros)

    \printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: dmso]